# Does static make a difference for a const local variable?

Tags: c++, static, constants

Imagine the following declaration:

```
void foo(){
    const std::array<int, 80000> arr = {/* a lot of different values*/};
    //do stuff
}
```

And a second one:

```
void foo(){
    static const std::array<int, 80000> arr = {/* a lot of different values*/};
    //do stuff
}
```

What are the possible performance differences between these two if any? And is there any danger associated with any of these solutions?

Comment: In the `static` case they may not be on the stack, but in a read-only section. Probably compiler dependent as well.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher won't good compiler place also non-static in read-only section?

Comment: actually I liked the example better before, now there is no point in using the arrays as they are just a obfuscated way to get a value `0`

Comment: out of curiosity: do you have a real problem at hand, or is this just an academic exercise? (its a valid question in both cases)

Comment: @user463035818 I am having discussion during code review ;)

Comment: depending on the reviewer that can be a real problem :P

Comment: I made a little [sample on godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/N2PRBP) but I've difficulties to interprete it...

Comment: @Scheff `withoutStatic` builds the array each times it is invoked from static data (`.LC0`). `withStatic` uses an array whose construction has been optimized as a constant (`withStatic()::arr`).

Comment: @YSC ...sounds like an answer. (I missed the copying - thanks.)

Comment: In the case of `std::array<int, N>`, you could make it `static constexpr std::array<int, N>`. This is ideal if it is achievable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> And is there any danger associated with any of these solutions?

Non-static is dangerous because the array is huge, and the memory reserved for automatic storage is limited. Depending on the system and configuration, that array could use about 30% of the space available for automatic storage. As such, it greatly increases the possibility of stack overflow.

While an optimiser might certainly avoid allocating memory on the stack, there are good reasons why you would want your non-optimised debug build to also not crash.

Answer (score 16):

Forget the array for a moment. That muddles two separate issues. You've got answers that address the **lifetime and storage** issue. I'll address the **initialization** issue.

```
void f() {
    static const int x = get_x();
    // do something with x
}

void g() {
    const int x = get_x();
    // do something with x
}
```

The difference between these two is that the first one will only call `get_x()` the first time that `f()` is called; `x` retains that value through the remainder of the program. The second one will call `get_x()` each time that `g()` is called.

That matters if `get_x()` returns different values on subsequent calls:

```
int current_x = 0;
int get_x() { return current_x++; }
```

Answer (score 6):

> What are the possible performance differences between these two if any?And is there any danger associated with any of these solutions?

The difference depends exactly on how you use `foo()`.

1st case:(low probability): Your implementation is such that you will call `foo()` only once , maybe you have created separate function to divide code logic as practiced. Well in this case declaring as static is very bad, because a static variable or object remains in memory until programs ends . So just imagine that your variable occupying memory unnecessarily.

2nd case:(high probability): Your implementation is such that you will call `foo()` again and again . Then non-static object will get allocated and de allocated again and again.This will take huge amount of cpu clock cycles which is not desired .Use static in this case.

Answer (score 3):

In this particular context, one point to consider regarding using `static` on a variable with initialization:

From C++17 standard:

> 6.7.1 Static storage duration [[basic.stc.static]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.stc.static)
>   ...
>   [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.stc.static#2) If a variable with static storage duration **has initialization** or a destructor with side effects, *it shall not be eliminated even if it appears to be unused*, except that a class object or its copy/move may be eliminated as specified in 15.8.